# Configure WCF Service to enable HTTPS and Transport Credential with User Name and Password

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, https

I have created a WCF Service and it works fine. Now I need to configure it to enable Transport Credentials with User Name and Password, and use HTTPS instead of HTTP. (Without using and certificates)

This is my existing configuration

```
<services>
  <service name="MySAPService">
    <endpoint address=""
                binding="wsHttpBinding"
                contract="MyService.IMyService" />
    <endpoint address="mex"
      binding="mexHttpBinding"
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

I googled about this and did not manage to find exact article appropriate for my scenario.

What are the changes I have to make to enable HTTPS and use User Name, Password authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say HTTPS it implies SSL, SSL requires Certificate (Now a certificate can be any certificate, self signed, untrusted CA etc.).

Now coming to the second part username & password, for that you need to set `clientCredentialType="Basic"` if you want to send them in plain text.

HTTPS/SSL/Certificates is over and above Username/Password authentication.

Answer (score 2):

To enable Https, change

```
<serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
         </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
```

and add `<security mode="Transport"/>` in the `<webHttpBinding>`.

for User Name, Password authentication use the following link:
[link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96028/WCF-Service-with-custom-username-password-authenti)

Comment: Thanks for the Answer :). Do I have to always use a Certificate to enable UserName, Password authentication? Can I use `TransportCredentialOnly` without a Certificate?

Comment: this is because WCF does not permit sending of the clear password over unsecured transport